# Deletion votes not being recorded on user profile?

Tags: bug, voting, profile-page, vote-to-delete

The votes tab on my user profile doesn't seem to be recording my delete votes, whether a post was deleted from Moderator Dashboard or from individual posts.

For instance, on my Super User profile, it indicates that the last deletion vote I had cast was on January 9th. Given the number of posts I delete, I know this is not true.

My latest post deletion was [this post](https://superuser.com/a/584768/4377) done about an hour ago, but my profile hasn't recorded that vote, neither has it recorded many other delete votes.

Comment: I _think_ the delete votes tab only shows delete votes on posts that aren't deleted yet (or have since been undeleted), at least for normal users. If it's the same for mods, given your vote is binding...

Comment: I don't know why the delete vote is not shown to the person who cast it. Given that they cast the delete vote, they should have the ability to view it to review it on a later date.

Comment: @Mat hm, quick glance and most of the ones that are listed on the tab seem to have been undeleted

Comment: @nhahtdh yeah, precisely